# How does group difficulty work in Reaper of Souls?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the new flex difficulty which is based on your level how does monster strength work?

E.g. If I am level 60 and my friend is level 20 will the monsters be equivalent to my level or his?

Comment: This is not specific to RoS. You can play using a level 60 and a level 20 in the same game in non-expansion. This will probably get closed as a dupe of the existing question from before the patch. To actually provide you an answer: The enemies will scale to the party leader.

Answer (score 6):

The monster level is equivalent to the party leader level. If you join your level 20 friend's party with your level 60 character, you're going to have a good time, if it's the other way arround they might not have that much fun.